# ssh to production to www-data user

Tags: bash, ssh, automation, productivity

I build an automation for deploys, that we connect to our productions servers and then perform a git pull in the project.

The project is owned by "www-data" so I need to to -->

```
ssh www-data@10.10.10.10
```

I read that it is not secure to do that,

is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add your user account to the www-data group. This will usually be all you need. If you have some files\directories which for some reason are not readable by the www-data group and you don't want to change them, then use sudo (if you have it; otherwise you'll want to just log in and use `su -` to modify the files). The reason it is a bad idea to log in as www-data via sudo is two fold. First, it is just annoying to create a home directory for www-data when it isn't needed. Secondly (and much more importantly), you don't want to allow **any** of the built in accounts to login via ssh. The reason that is a problem is because now a hacker only needs to guess the password. With your regular user account they'd also need to guess the user name. This advise mostly applies to the root account but it is also valid for www-data.